# Android : AsyncTask onPostExecute is getting null reply

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android application in which I am using AsyncTask in the same class as the activity. Before I had a thread model where I would join the thread and wait until I have a reply. But as it locks the UI, I am migrating my code to Async-task. Going smoothly for other methods, but I am getting an error where there is nothing is recieved.

As the server is in localhost itself, i am logging that I sent out a reply. Also, it works with Thread nicely. What am I doing wrong?

Error log :

```
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime: Process: internetlegion.twentynotes, PID: 31746
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()' on a null object reference
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at internetlegion.twentynotes.Activity.GroupAccountActivity$getGroupAccountsForLoggedInUser.onPostExecute(GroupAccountActivity.java:125)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at internetlegion.twentynotes.Activity.GroupAccountActivity$getGroupAccountsForLoggedInUser.onPostExecute(GroupAccountActivity.java:108)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
10-14 13:47:00.917 31746-31746/internetlegion.twentynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

GroupAccountActivity :

```
public class GroupAccountActivity extends Activity {

    private ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]> responseEntity;

    GroupAccountAdapter groupAccountAdapter;

    final String groupAccountRetrieveURL = StaticRestTemplate.baseURL+"getgroupsforuser/";
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_account);

        if(isOnline()) {
            new getGroupAccountsForLoggedInUser().execute();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
  public class getGroupAccountsForLoggedInUser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]>>{

        @Override
        protected ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
            requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            return restTemplate.exchange(groupAccountRetrieveURL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, RestGroupAccount[].class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]> entity) {
            super.onPostExecute(entity);
// Line below is throwing error.
            RestGroupAccount[] restGroupAccounts = responseEntity.getBody();
            Collections.addAll(restGroupAccountList, restGroupAccounts);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> groupList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}

}
```

Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are referencing the wrong object in onPostExecute. You should reference the result object/parameter.

Change your code to:

```
RestGroupAccount[] restGroupAccounts = entity.getBody();
```

Comment: That was naive of me. Thanks a lot. :-) I will accept your answer in 11 minutes as SO says I cannot now.

Answer (score 2):

`responseEntity` is never initialize.

I think you wanted to do

```
RestGroupAccount[] restGroupAccounts = entity.getBody();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the error. What you do is

`RestGroupAccount[] restGroupAccounts = responseEntity.getBody();`

But in the onPostExecute the response is called `entity`.

You declared responseEntity above like:

`private ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]> responseEntity;`

But that one doesn't contain the response.

Try changing

`RestGroupAccount[] restGroupAccounts = responseEntity.getBody();`

To

`RestGroupAccount[] restGroupAccounts = entity.getBody();`